# Twilio token not found when doing the QuickStart

Tags: php, ios, twilio, twilio-php

Context: I am following the instructions provided in the Twilio iOS [Quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/quickstart-ios) to test out the Chat function. A simple PHP server is required to generate tokens.

Inside `token.php`, these are the lines to generate the token:

```
$token = new AccessToken(
    $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, 
    $TWILIO_API_KEY, 
    $TWILIO_API_SECRET, 
    3600, 
    $identity
);
```

The instructions only asked me to modify `config.php`, which I have:

```
<?php
// Required for all uses
$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = 'actual_SID';
$TWILIO_API_KEY = 'actual_API_key';
$TWILIO_API_SECRET = 'actual_API_secret';

// Required for Video
$TWILIO_CONFIGURATION_SID = '';

// Required for Chat
$TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID = 'actual_Chat_Service_SID';

// Required for Notify
$TWILIO_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_SID = '';

// Required for Sync
$TWILIO_SYNC_SERVICE_SID = '';
```

As they have instructed, I run the server with `php -S localhost:8000 -t webroot` and get the following error:

```
/token.php?device=browser - Class 'Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken' not found in /Users/me/Downloads/sdk-starter-php-master/webroot/token.php on line 19
```

Comment: Did you install the dependencies with `composer install` ?

Comment: @philnash Thank you. That did the trick!

Comment: Ah, cool! I'll pop that in as a real answer so that others can see it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Before running the application with `php -S localhost:8000 -t webroot` make sure you have installed the dependencies using composer:

```
composer install
```

Then you should be ready to run.

Comment: Thanks! This did it.